# Как считать информацию с сайта после всех подгрузок с помощью requests

Tags: python, requests, запрос, get

```
html=session.get(link, headers=headers).content.decode('utf-8')
```

Сервер подгружает **html-код** в 2 этапа: если при переходе на страницу быстро пролистать вниз, то **оставшаяся часть загрузится через временную задержку**. В указанную выше переменную html переносится только первая часть страницы (до скроллинга).

Как *указать для requests.get() ожидание* полной прогрузки страницы?

(чтобы получить полный html-код)

Comment: Никак. Используйте другие библиотеки. К примеру `selenium` или `requests-html`

Comment: @Namerek вообще, получить можно и через requests, надо через инспектор браузера посмотреть интересующий запрос, который подгружает вторую часть контента и имитировать его через requests, ну а там уже в заисимости от типа возвращаемых данных он либо html либо json получит. Ну а как первую часть получать, думаю объяснять не нужно)

Comment: @Spartak, вы сейчас отправили топикстартера заниматься чистой воды онанизмом.

Comment: @Namerek Да в принципе тоже нормальный вариант, если там ответ в нормальном виде приходит.